# Why UseAuthentication must be before UseMvc in NET Core 2.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In NET Core 2.0 when I have:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();
```

My app handles correctly JWT authorization header, but when above lines are in a different order

```
app.UseMvc();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

magic can happen. Like **for the first request, everything is fine but second, received 401 response** (this behaviour is the most interesting).

So the question is why the order of this two middlewares has such strange impact? **I understand the correct order, but I don't understand the strange behaviour in first request**

Comment: Describing Mvc as middleware may be technically correct but since it, more often than not, generates the response itself, it'll rarely chain to any middleware configured later than it.

Comment: Take a look at the Ordering section of documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#ordering

Comment: @tpeczek still I don't understand magic in first request :)

Comment: @PiotrStapp In general when you are setting up middlewares they are building a chain-of-responsibility. If `UseAuthentication()` is first it checks the JWT authorization header and sets the `User` property on request. So, when MVC inspects the `User` property it is valid and MVC servers the response. When `UseMvc` is first it inspects the `User` property before it's set, from its perspective the request is unathorized (anonymous user) so it returns 401 and the authentication middleware never runs.

Comment: @PiotrStapp Only now I see your update regarding multiple requests. As noticed in the answear below it strongly depends on routing and if MVC middleware pickups the request or not (also if the action picking up the request requires authentication or not).

Comment: @PiotrStapp there's no magic. Authentication should always occur as early as possible, definitely before a request even reaches the framework much less the controller. The behaviour isn't strange either - the first request is ALWAYS anonymous. If authentication is required, the server returns a 401 and the browser responds with authentication headers etc. Use Fiddler to inspect the actual flow. MVC retrieves either properly anonymous requests or properly authenticated.

Comment: @PiotrStapp  By *reversing* them, you force MVC  to handle anonymous requests *before* the authentication middleware has a chance to authenticate anything or route to the login form. It may well route an anonymous request to a controller that requires authentication

Comment: @piotrstapp so you tells that Mvc middleware keeps some state which passes first request but fails on second, is that right? Of course we all understand how the pipeline is working on middleware layer, we all know that order matters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the order of how middlewares declared in `Configure` method actually matters. The middlewares define the pipeline which a request will go through. The simplest middleware can be defined like this

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

In this example the code before `next.Invoke()` will be executed before request is passed to next middleware in the chain. And everything what goes after it will be executed when all subsequent middlewares have been executed. Now to your question the authentication middleware is defined before MVC because in this way the authentication middleware can stop a request and return HTTP status 403 if it cannot be authenticated or HTTP status 302 to redirect request to a login page.

As for your specific case the first request most likely matched the configured route so request was handled by MVC controller and generated response w/o passing it to the next (authentication) middlware. For second request (I guess it's different one) the MVC framework didn't find a router matched by this request so it just forwarded it to next middleware hoping that it knows how to process it.

Another reason would be that first request hit action which doesn't require request to be authorized, when another request hit the one which requires authorization.

Comment: I know that order matters. I don't understand strange/magic logic during the first request. If the order is wrong it should never work

Comment: @PiotrStapp authentication occurs (and *should always* occur) before a request reaches a framework