# asp.net core 2.0 Authorization is firing before authentication (JWT)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-authorization

I'm attempting to implement a custom authorization policy in my asp.net core 2.0 application.

In my Custom AuthorizationHandler I have this check:

```
if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
     this.logger.LogInformation("Failed to authorize user.  User is not authenticated.");
     return Task.CompletedTask;
 }
 // ... More authorization checks
```

which makes sense, as unauthenticated users are not authorized for my controller action.

I'm using JWT bearer auth and have it configured like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
    {

        cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        cfg.SaveToken = true;

        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = "<issuer>",
            ValidAudience = "<audience>",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingKey)),
            ValidateLifetime = false
        };

    });
```

I'm also registering my authorization requirement and handler (note these registrations happen AFTER I've configured authentication above, and BEFORE I call `serivces.AddMVC()`:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(Constants.AuthorizationPolicies.MyCustomPolicy,
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MyCustomRequirement()));
});
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MyCustomAuthorizationHandler>();
```

Here's my problem, It appears my Authorization Policy is executing before the jwt token is being challenged and validated, as a result, my authorization policy is failing because the user is not authenticated.

Here's a log of a sample call:

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:60235
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[14:50:57 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:60235/api/values application/json
[14:51:03 INF] Failed to authorize user.  User is not authenticated.
[14:51:03 INF] Authorization failed for user: null.
[14:51:03 INF] Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
[14:51:03 INF] Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ([]).
[14:51:03 INF] Successfully validated the token.
[14:51:03 INF] AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
[14:51:03 INF] Executed action AuthorizationTestClient.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (AuthorizationTestClient) in 5819.1586ms
[14:51:03 INF] Request finished in 5961.5619ms 401
```

As you can see, the authorization policy executes first, fails because the user isn't authenticated and then the authentication challenge happens.

Shouldn't this be the other way around?  How do I tell asp.net to perform authentication before authorization?

Comment: Have you read this? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I'm also registering my authorization requirement and handler (note
>   these registrations happen AFTER I've configured authentication above,
>   and BEFORE I call serivces.AddMVC()

The order of services registration in DI container is not quite important. What **is** important it's the order of middleware registration in `Startup.Configure` method. You have not provided the code of this method, but I bet you add authentication middleware after MVC middleware or don't add it at all. Authentication middleware should be added before MVC, so make sure your `Startup.Configure` looks similar to this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Check following articles for more details:

- [ASP.NET Core Middleware -
  Ordering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#ordering)
- [Why UseAuthentication must be before UseMvc in NET Core
  2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276987/why-useauthentication-must-be-before-usemvc-in-net-core-2-0)

Answer (score -14):

Ok.. turns out it was very easy fix. I needed a call to app.UseAuthentication() in my Configure method.  Silly me!

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Comment: Well, why do you post the same answer that I have posted?

Comment: I agree, you should delete your answer and accept @CodeFuller's answer

Comment: I actually posted my response 4 mins before codeFuller posted his.

Comment: Hover the mouse over "answered ..." label above username. My answer is "2018-03-20 19:20:27Z", your answer is "2018-03-20 19:24:00Z", which is 4 minutes later. Sorting answers by oldest tab also shows correct order.

Comment: Just accept CodeFuller's answer, don't repeat previous answers.